# A non-trivial upper bound on the integral of Lipschitz functions over a bounded support

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, integration

Let $x \in \mathcal{X} = [0,1]^n$, and $f(x)$ be an $L$-Lipschitz function. Let $f(0)=0$. What is (the exact or a non-trivial upper bound on) $\int_{x\in\mathcal{X}} |f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x$?What about $\int_{x\in\mathcal{X}} |f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: Take $f=C$, $C$ constant.  Then the integrals can be made arbitrarily  large by choosing  $C$ appropriately.

Comment: Agree. But what if we add additional constraints like $ f(0)=0$?

Comment: I have added this assumption.

Comment: How is this either algebraic geometry or differential geometry?

Comment: @NikWeaver Because it uses $^2$ and $dx$ LOL.

Comment: @FanZheng best possible answer!

Answer (score 4):

If $f:[0,1]^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is $L$-Lipschitz and $f(0)=0$, then $|f(x)|\le L\|x\|$, which obviously implies that the function $x\mapsto L\|x\|$ is the maximizer for both problems.

Comment: This example generalizes to $f(x)=|x|$ on $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: @Fan Zheng it was a typo.  fixed